# Writing to a text file doesn't update unless I refresh

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to allow a user to download an xml file with coordinate information. I use the following to create a download button:

```
<a download href='XML_Data.xml'><input type='button' value='XML Data' onclick='loadXML()'></a>
```

Below is my loadXML() function:

```
function loadXML()
{
    <?php
        //clear the file
        file_put_contents("XML_Data.xml", "");

        $handle = fopen("XML_Data.xml", "w+");
        fwrite($handle, "<ANNOTATIONS>\r\n");

        //markers
        $sql = "SELECT coords, color, annot_type FROM cbmarker.annot_test WHERE
        project_id='$pid' 
        AND userid=" . $_SESSION['Id'] .
        " AND image=\"" . $pic .
        "\" AND annot_type='marker'
        ORDER BY id ASC";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {           
            $markerX = $row['coords'];
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
            $markerY = $row['coords'];

            fwrite($handle, "  <annotation annot_type='marker' color='" . $row['color'] . "' X='" . $markerX . "' Y='" . $markerY . "' />\r\n");
        } 

        fwrite($handle, "</ANNOTATIONS>\r\n");
        fclose($handle);
    ?>
```

When I add additional entries to the database that the query should grab, the text file doesn't contain them. However, when I refresh the page, everything works fine. Does anybody know why the text file won't update until after I refresh even though the database does update before I refresh?

Thanks

Comment: Stop using the deprecated MySQL extension. Start by migrating to MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding about how PHP works. It runs on the server when you request the page. You can't put PHP code inside a Javascript function. You need to use AJAX to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what happens:

1. You request the page that has the JavaScript code shown
2. Since some of that page contains PHP code, that PHP code runs *on the server*, and returns *to the browser* the rendered HTML including JavaScript.
3. That rendered HTML is then rendered in the browser.  The JavaScript that you downloaded as part of the page *does not change* because the PHP code will not be re-executed in the browser.  It was only executed to render the HTML + JavaScript that is now in the browser.
4. When you refresh the page, the web browser queries the server again, and *new JavaScript* is generated on the server by running the PHP again there.

If you want the page to automatically display new items without entirely refreshing, you can use a timer to make a periodic Ajax query back to the server to look for updates to the data.